# Unable to filter value in Firebase Database using Query

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a chat app and when a user clicks on the profile of another user, I make a check if a chat already exists with this User using below code:

```
   FirebaseUser fu = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
   String fuId = fu.getUid();
   DatabaseReference queryRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    Query query = queryRef.child("chats").child(fuId).orderByChild("otherUsersName").equalTo("Tim Cook");

    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
                //open the exsiting chat
            }else{
                //start a new chat
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Here is my database snapshot:

[image]

Since there is a value named "Tim Cook" and I am clicking on Tim Cook's profile, it should open existing chat activity but everytime a new chat activity is opened and my query is not working properly. I wanted to know what mistake I am doing and also it is the good technique or should I approach it in another way?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because you are missing a child. As i see in your screen-shot, the `chatId` is missing. To solve this, please change this line of code:

```
FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
String uid = firebaseUser.getUid();

DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference userIdRef = rootRef.child("chats").child(uid);
Query query = userIdRef.orderByChild("otherUsersName").equalTo("Tim Cook");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            if (ds.exists()) {
                Log.d("TAG", ds.child("otherUsersName").getValue(String.class));
                //open the exsiting chat
            } else {
                //start a new chat
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Comment: But since there can be many chats for a user, I don't know what chatId is. I need to search from all chats and find a match.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I still have one question. If there are many chats for a particular user, will this code become slow and is this the best approach to do?

Comment: You're welcome! The best option that I recomand you, is to use denormalization. Please see the following tutorial, [Denormalization is normal with the Firebase Database](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vKqXSZLLnHA).

Comment: When I ran this code, I see that code inside second value event listener is not getting called and no activity is started.

Comment: Please see again my updated answer. Soory but i'm just wrting code, not actually testing. Does it work this time?

Comment: Again the same problem. Every time a new chat activity is launched.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154984/discussion-between-mehul-kanzariya-and-alex-mamo).

Comment: I am not getting any error and everytime a new chat activity is started.

Comment: How are you starting the new activity?